# How to fix the line that are cut-off when showing content from HTML to WebView in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview

While showing content in a `WebView` the lines on the top and bottom are cut off. How to fix this issue. I am using `HTML` to show data in the `WebView`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the issue you are having from your description. Can you post an image or post some code?

Comment: Since its my 1st question I am not able to upload the image. If you can suggest me some other way, I can send you the image there.

Comment: For the time being, you can probably just use http://tinypic.com/ (or so I've heard) for uploading a quick image. I would assume that the issue is with the HTML itself. Can you describe what you mean by lines on the top and bottom, or post the HTML if it's not too large?

Comment: [Image](http://tinypic.com/r/2dmbble/8). I have to omit  the part marked in red.

Answer (score 0):

Setting padding top and padding bottom didn't work.

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

**WorkAround 1:**
Add padding in your html file body tag, if your loading it from your assets folder.

```
<html><body style='padding:10px;'>
```

**WorkAround 2:**
Add webview in a layout and set padding on that layout. like below.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have tried this and it did not work.